# Lead on datastage for timestamp?

Tags: datastage

I need to use the `Lead` function on `Datastage` with the column timestamp, but when I need to put the next column `substriting-10 minutes`, if someone did it before I tried, and I had also, that can't put strings on the timestamp.

How can I solve this problem?

**Input**

```
Id | date.             |
1 | 01/04/2016 13:45:25|
2 | 10/04/2016 01:25:36|
3 | 26/10/2017 22:35:13|
```

**Output**

```
Id| date.               | Befor.             |
1 | 01/04/2016 13:45:25 | 10/04/2016 01:15:36|
2 | 10/04/2016 01:25:36 | 26/10/2017 22:35:13|
3 | 26/10/2017 22:35:13 |null                |
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please follow the rules of [How to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). At best you edit your question to include your efforts and problems in detail. Thanks!

Comment: Where do you want to use "Lead" in the SQL of a connector or a Transformer or what? Please describe more details ...

Comment: In Oracle connector